# Gradle - Delete not working

Tags: gradle

I want to append some extra delete functionality to the clean task (for Java builds).

So I try adding the following to my gradle build script.

```
clean.doLast{
    delete ('test.txt')
}
```

When I tun the "clean" task my sample file doesn't get deleted ... I also don't get any error message indicated what happened.

If I try the following:

```
task deleteStuff(type: Delete) {
    delete 'test.txt'
}
```

Things do work.

Can I not add (via doLast) delete functionality to tasks? What is the proper way of doing this (without hacking in Ant tasks).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In these two code snippets, you aren't calling `Project.delete()` but `Delete.delete()`. In other words, you are configuring the `Delete` task. Doing this after the `Delete` task has executed (as in the first snippet) is too late.

In the case of a `Delete` task, there is no good reason to add a `delete` operation with `doLast`. Your second snippet is clearly preferable. For other tasks, the `doLast` approach will work because they don't have a `delete` method. Or you can disambiguate with `project.delete()`.

Comment: Peter, thanks for mentioning project.delete to disambiguate.  That cleared up a lot of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason is to avoid spending time in the preparation phase (which is executed for every task), doFirst can be used to set up the Delete-task.
So using clean.doFirst instead of clean.doLast in the example above will work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
task deleteTestFile(type:Delete) {
    delete 'test.txt'
}
clean.dependsOn deleteTestFile
```